# Get 2d np.array row indices depending on other 2d np.array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I want to fetch all row indicies of an 2d np.array on the basis of another 2d np.array.

Input:
`all_elements = np.array([[1, 1], [2, 2], [3, 3]])`
`elements = np.array([[1, 1],[2, 2]])`

Something like:

`idx = np.row_idx(elements, all_elements, axis=0)`
output:
`[0, 1]`

I have been trying to do this with some version of `np.where(np.isin(.....))` but i can't get it to work properly.
Any1 have any tips?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IIUC, you might want to use:

```
np.where((all_elements==elements[:,None]).all(2).any(0))[0]
```

output: `array([0, 1])`

explanation:

```
# compare all elements using broadcasting
(all_elements==elements[:,None])

array([[[ True,  True],
        [False, False],
        [False, False]],

       [[False, False],
        [ True,  True],
        [False, False]]])

# all True on the last dimension
(all_elements==elements[:,None]).all(2)

array([[ True, False, False],
       [False,  True, False]])

# any match per first dimension
(all_elements==elements[:,None]).all(2).any(0)

array([ True,  True, False])
```

Comment: this is to add an extra dimension to `elements` (to go 3D to perform the comparison element-wise)